# R how to pool years into periods

Tags: r

I would like to pool several years into periods of 5-years. I have data from 1986 to 2016. Basically I want period 1 to consist of years 1986-1991, period 2 1992-1996 and so on. Anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach via `ifelse`:

Illustrative data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  year = sample(1986:2016, 20))
```

Solution:

```
df$period <- ifelse(df$year >= 1986 & df$year <= 1990, "period1",
                    ifelse(df$year >= 1991 & df$year <= 1995, "period2",
                           ifelse(df$year >= 1996 & df$year <= 2000, "period3",
                                  ifelse(df$year >= 2001 & df$year <= 2005, "period4",
                                         ifelse(df$year >= 2006 & df$year <= 2010, "period5", "period6")))))
```

Result:

```
df
   year  period
1  1994 period2
2  2009 period5
3  1997 period3
4  2010 period5
5  2011 period6
6  1987 period1
7  1999 period3
8  2007 period5
9  1998 period3
10 1996 period3
11 2006 period5
12 1995 period2
13 2008 period5
14 2015 period6
15 2012 period6
16 2000 period3
17 1989 period1
18 1986 period1
19 1990 period1
20 2014 period6
```

**EDIT**:

Another solution is via `dplyr`:

First define a vector with your period limits:

```
limits <- c(1986, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2016)
```

Then group the `year` values by these `limits`:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(group = findInterval(year, limits))
```

Result:

```
df1
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   group [6]
    year period    group
   <int> <list>    <int>
 1  1994 <lgl [1]>     2
 2  2009 <lgl [1]>     5
 3  1997 <lgl [1]>     3
 4  2010 <lgl [1]>     6
 5  2011 <lgl [1]>     6
 6  1987 <lgl [1]>     1
 7  1999 <lgl [1]>     3
 8  2007 <lgl [1]>     5
 9  1998 <lgl [1]>     3
10  1996 <lgl [1]>     3
11  2006 <lgl [1]>     5
12  1995 <lgl [1]>     3
13  2008 <lgl [1]>     5
14  2015 <lgl [1]>     6
15  2012 <lgl [1]>     6
16  2000 <lgl [1]>     4
17  1989 <lgl [1]>     1
18  1986 <lgl [1]>     1
19  1990 <lgl [1]>     2
20  2014 <lgl [1]>     6
```